# I never have enough votes on area51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, voting-limits

There are so many questions on [one of the proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) on area51 that I follow, that I spend all my votes on it, and am unable to get to any of the other proposals.

How about some more votes please?

**Edit:**  See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52024/asking-and-voting-for-good-and-bad-questions-in-area-51) about how questions and voting are supposed to work on Area51.

Answer (score 7):

You already have 100!

The idea with voting on Area 51 isn't to vote on every single question, but to vote on the **best** on-topic and off-topic questions.

Comment: It's hard to avoid voting on all (as they are all either on or off-topic)

Comment: 100? Well that's a relief. The first few days we only had 30 IIRC.

Comment: I thought the point was to vote on all the questions, as to whether they're off or on-topic, so as to define the site.  How can an off-topic question be __best__?

Comment: @Jon, maybe they did raise the votes, I only remember having around 30.

Comment: Yeah, they raised the votes thanks to me and probably a few others. I emailed them about and said there is no way that 30 will work. 100 is about right.

Comment: I only get 5 votes for each category, which is _way_ too low. Am I missing something?