# Describe reasons why a example question is on topic

Tags: feature-request, area-51

In the current Area-51 proposals the only way to explain why an example question is exemplary is to add a comment, leading to a lot of sample questions which are really basic.

Would it be possible to add a mandatory field when entering example questions explaining why that question is exemplary in being on/off topic? This would then allow people to identify expert questions easily when voting, as described in [Asking and voting for good (and bad) questions in Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52024/asking-and-voting-for-good-and-bad-questions-in-area-51)

Comment: I agree that this feature is sorely lacking.  It is hard to describe questions that are specific enough to be on topic in such a small amount of space.

Answer (score 1):

I have also notice this.  However, I have also noticed that having only a space to put in a question title causes me to think more deeply about the questions I might ask, as it forces me to express my question as succinctly (using as few words) as possible.

Where good questions are being asked, the question titles are representative of a body of questions.  Putting a specific paragraph in a question would confine that question to a specific question only.  IMO, for a site that doesn't even exist yet, this strikes me as a bit too focused.

A comment, to the effect of: "I believe this is a good question because..." should suffice.

Comment: It's too bad this practice is not encouraged on SO, as many of the question titles people post there are just horrendous.

Comment: Yes, a short blurb should be all that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This would also allow to use the default SE search for related questions to avoid duplicates after entering the question.