# Please add tags to proposed questions on Area51

Tags: feature-request, tags, area-51

I'm starting to see proposed questions suffixed with "tags" #LikeThis on Area51. I think tags in a question help to bring additional information to the question that doesn't necessarily belong as part of the question itself, [e.g.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming/1411#1411),

> How to take down Void Ray rush as Protoss? #Starcraft2

The tagging schema for a proposed site is important too, and voting on questions with tags will help to shape it.

Comment: I think that workaround is valid.

Also, you can specify in the comments that it's talking about starcraft 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [The Cat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/54262/the-cat) and I have been discussing in the comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms), the sets of tags between Stack Exchange sites need to be kept separated. Unfortunately, that is the exact opposite of what's going on with the proposal site -- it's a discussion area for *all* proposals. Therefore, any tag system would need to be completely segregated by proposal. I think this *could* be implemented, but it would be quite a lot of work.

Secondly, and more importantly, I don't think a tag system is even necessary. There shouldn't be a need to categorize the questions of a proposal if all the questions are of high quality (as Robert Cartaino details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52024/asking-and-voting-for-good-and-bad-questions-in-area-51)). For example, how many example questions about Starcraft are necessary? If there are *that* many, then maybe (a) the lower-quality ones should be removed, and/or (b) a new Starcraft-based proposal should be started.

Comment: The tags don't need to be anything indexable or functional, just descriptive of the types of tags one might see on the site. (Heck, the whole implementation could be just to reformat and reposition the `#Tags` in the question.) In addition, tags of downvoted questions will help to define the domains of questions that are inappropriate for the site. My request is addressing something the community is already starting to do. If that's the direction they are going, why not give them the tools?

Comment: @fbrereto: I think the tags that would end up on a site would come from the topics in the sample questions. (When a new site is started, it is seeded with questions, and at that point, a set of tags would be created.) I don't see a need to preselect a set of tags -- it's recording the same information in two different formats.

Comment: I was going to make a very similar proposal.
For example if I want to share the http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters with the "share" link it would add something like "#stxchn-prowebmasters.

That way you could be able to track the hype on a proposal on twitter.

That would be an interesting feature, the implementation could be as simple as adding another field while creating the proposed community, and make it optional in case the creator does not want to use it. 
In my mind should be fairly simple to implement and should not add too much overhead in the app.

Answer (score 1):

As a clarification, I added some 'tags', because some people have absolutely NO idea what topic the question is about. This at least gives them a feeling whether it feels legit. Do we need tags? Perhaps when it goes into Beta

Answer (score 0):

I think tags are better accomplished during the site's bootstrap phase. We're already dealing with overload on area51 as it is.