# Tagging for Area 51 proposals desperately needed

Tags: feature-request, tags, area-51

It has become unwieldy to browse Stack Exchange proposals on Area 51. There are more than 900 proposals, more than 18 pages if 50 proposals are shown per page.

If it was possible to tag proposals and use tag inclusion/exclusion in view filtering then it would be more manageable. For example, it would be possible to filter out all the proposals that are really small subsets of (or closely related to)  Stack Overflow or otherwise computer related (if they were tagged with `software-development` , `programming`, `computing`, etc.).

Examples from some 100 proposals include

- [FOSS Finder](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11317/foss-finder),
- [Office Development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10858/office-development),
- [IBM Mainframes](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10775/ibm-mainframes),
- [NoSql](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10713/nosql),
- [Object Oriented & Functional - Design Patterns](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10560/object-oriented-functional-design-patterns),
- [Software Architecture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10560/object-oriented-functional-design-patterns),
- [Game Theory](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10447/game-theory),
- [Windows Phone 7 Development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10416/windows-phone-7-development),
- [Linked Data Queries](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10408/linked-data-queries),
- [Software Testing (in Portuguese)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10120/software-testing-in-portuguese),
- [Erlang](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9940/erlang),
- [ANTLR](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10237/antlr),
- [History of Computers and Computing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9912/history-of-computers-and-computing),
- [Magento](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9869/magento),
- [Reverse Engineering (Software)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9845/reverse-engineering-software),
- [Microsoft .NET Micro Framework](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9787/microsoft-net-micro-framework),
- [Image Processing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9746/image-processing),
- [Development Methodologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9543/development-methodologies),
- [Joomla Answers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9494/joomla-answers),
- [MongoDB](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9408/mongodb) and
- [Shell Hackers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9386/shell-hackers).

The same goes for other classifications, for example games, sports, science, language/writing, etc.

Do you think a tagging system for Area 51 is a good idea?

---

Related, but is about tagging for **example questions**, not **proposals**: *[Please add tags to proposed questions on Area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52192/please-add-tags-to-proposed-questions-on-area51)*.

Comment: +1 Agree that they need categorization, or at least some way to search them by topic.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a looser display so you could get more on the screen at once, like displaying `title`/`num followers` and a brief description in small text, hiding the *define/commit/beta* bar for each.

Then a CTRL+F search on a single page will help you find what you're looking for.  Allow 1000 per page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm against this. I don't find it that unwieldy to navigate the area 51, there is a search box and all that. These are seedling proposals, some of which are going to be thinned out, so there is no point making a ton of effort categorizing them. I've deleted two of my own proposals and lots more are going to get thinned out so don't waste time organizing things too hard yet. Wait until they are in beta or commitment before spending a lot of time doing that kind of busy-work.