# Why am I allowed to vote for my own questions on Area 51?

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, voting

I realized that I can vote as on-topic or off-topic on my own questions on Area 51. On the other sites, this is not allowed. Why am I allowed to vote for my own questions on Area 51? Do these self-votes count in daily voting limit?

**EDIT:** This should be "status-completed" now.

Comment: The opposite is now true. You can [no longer vote on your own questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52589/no-longer-able-to-vote-for-question-on-area51)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On-topic and off-topic voting on Area51 is something entirely different from good-answer/bad-answer voting on SO.

You are *encouraged* to post off-topic questions on Area51, because these help define the site just as well as on-topic questions. And there's nothing wrong with saying "Here's a proposed question that fits the overall topic, but I think it shouldn't be on the site".

The Area51 equivalent of downvoting isn't off-topic voting, but voting to delete.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52203/change-on-topic-to-belong

Comment: Deleting is just barely an equivalent for downvoting: it only takes 3 and then it's just .. gone, plus you're limited to just **three** per day.  Some of the differences [could be changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52232/more-deletion-votes-for-example-questions) easily, though.

Comment: @The Cat: "equivalent" as in "this is crap and shouldn't be here" (where "here" is Area51 itself). Also, it has the same rep implications as "regular" downvoting (-1 for voter, -2 for votee)

Comment: @balpha - This still seems strange to me. If you proposed the question, then you obviously feel it is either on-topic, or off-topic. Seems weird to allow you a vote to that effect as well as throw the question out to the community.

Comment: Some questions I've been unsure how to vote on when I asked them.  (I think this is generally a good indication of important questions to ask.)  @ire

Comment: @ire I agree with The Cat; in addition: Even *if* I "obviously feel it is either on-topic, or off-topic", why shouldn't I vote that way? In the sense of "Here's a question, I think it's off-topic, but everyone else has their say, too."

Answer (score 3):

They *do* count in the daily limit; I just tested that. But they don't affect your rep.  They do affect your badges (I might consider this a bug).

I think you should not be able to vote for your own example questions.  Of course, you may not want to, once the voting limit per proposal is implemented.  But as things currently stand, especially with votes visible, I wouldn't want to sway the voting with how I interpret the question—because what I meant to ask and what I actually asked are probably subtly different!

Comment: Going through and voting to hit the daily limit so I can test this is.. meh.. tiring.

Comment: @The Cat Thanks for the hard work of testing.

Answer (score 2):

From the number of zero vote questions, it seems most users haven't realised this yet. Who wouldn't vote on a question they proposed? The aim of posing a question is to provide an exemplary on or off-topic question. Therefore, if you bothered to propose the question, then you must clearly have an opinion one way or the other.

It seems redundant to allow this vote as is. If it is allowed, then for fairness, I think the vote should be required when the question is submitted.

Comment: I [ran out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52334/why-am-i-allowed-to-vote-for-my-own-questions-on-area-51/52335#52335) of votes today!