# No longer able to vote for question on Area51

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, questions, area-51, voting

I just went to Area51 to start voting over on the topics I follow, and now found that I can't vote for my own questions.  I purposely made those questions up to be good definers of the site (on and off-topic), and now I can't vote for them even though I think 'some' of them are best.  I actually put quite a bit of time into some of those, looking up references to make the questions more accurate.

How about just not giving me rep or credits for my own votes, but please let me vote for my own questions?  Otherwise, it's seems pretty pointless for me to be suggesting questions.

Answer (score 3):

Voting for your own questions is pointless. Everyone would do it, so it would just add +1 to every score.

Adding thoughtful questions is *not* pointless, as others will vote on them.

Comment: Ah, the vagaries of meta. I quite agree. But just yesterday, the [opposite opinion prevailed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52334/why-am-i-allowed-to-vote-for-my-own-questions-on-area-51/52337)

Answer (score 2):

If I believe some of my questions are great on or off topic questions, I should be able to vote on them (no rep of course)

I liked that you could do it before the rule changes