# Why can't you vote on your own questions on area51 anymore?

Tags: discussion, voting, area-51, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No longer able to vote for question on Area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52589/no-longer-able-to-vote-for-question-on-area51)

If I believe some of my questions are great on or off topic questions, I should be able to vote on them (no rep of course)

I liked that you could do it before the rule changes

Comment: I'm with you Juan, it's frustrating.