# Voting limit on Area51

Tags: feature-request, voting, area-51, voting-limits

I'm finding the 5 votes each for on and off topic per proposal a little small. What was the rationale behind this? I would find it more useful if i could give a vote on a larger proportion of the asked questions for a given proposal, especially since ones that get really going generate 100+ questions (where i then get to vote on 10 percent of them. Ooh.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52015/i-never-have-enough-votes-on-area51

Comment: @lc that post was from before they instituted the 5 on/off topic votes per proposal cap

Comment: **To close voters:** Area 51 Meta questions are [on-topic here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323569/377214). Only questions about specific proposals are off-topic.