# What Area 51 questions belong here as opposed to Area 51 Discussion Zone?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, area-51, meta, scope

There's an impressive body of Area 51-related questions here on Meta Stack Exchange, linked together with the [area51](/questions/tagged/area51) (1,688 questions as of the writing of this question) tag, but there is also a separate [Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), where most questions relate to individual proposals but sometimes broad questions about Area 51 itself or its general processes are seen. The [area51](/questions/tagged/area51) tag wiki recommends

> Area 51 has its own discussion site which acts as its own meta site. If a question is only related to Area 51, then it is better to ask it there.

but most of the Area 51 questions on this site (Meta Stack Exchange) seem to be fairly specific to Area 51.

Moving forward, what concepts should be considered when

- Deciding that an Area 51-related question belongs here on Meta Stack Exchange?
- Deciding that an Area 51-related question belongs on Area 51 Discussion Zone?

Comment: My personal opinion is that all questions related only to area 51 should be asked on area 51 discussions. I've never understood why we allowed questions here that relate only to area 51, considering we literally have a close reason for questions only applicable to one site in the network.

Comment: @BlueberryGumdrops Because Area 51 is not a Network Q&A site; it is a product and function of Stack Exchange (like Teams, Enterprise, and Stackapps, for example). Generally speaking, support for all Stack Exchange features/products are hosted here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino that's what I'm saying. MSE is for questions about the whole network, and Area 51 Discussions is for questions only related to Area 51 (in addition to discussing proposals).

Comment: @BlueberryGumdrops MSE is also about the company and its products. Area 51 is not a Network Q&A site in the sense of having it's own "meta support site". It is a product and function of Stack Exchange. That's why we named it "Area 51 Discussion Zone" instead of "Area 51 Meta".

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't matter. Either is fine.

The Discussion Zone (Area 51 meta) was originally intended to be a place for individual communities to discuss their proposals.

It didn't make sense to start harassing folks with a proposal to go to this entirely different system (meta.stackexchange) to ask a question about the software or the broader Area 51 process itself ("when will this proposal advance?"). Likewise, it doesn't make sense to irritate people here who've grown accustomed to getting their SE support on meta.SE to go somewhere else for that one Stack Exchange feature.

There's just nothing to be gained by it.