# Is it acceptable to cross-post here from Area 51 Discussion Zone, seeking advice about the scope of a proposed site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, scope, site-proposal

Is it acceptable to cross-post from Area 51 discussion zone when seeking advice about the scope of a proposed site?

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323569/what-area-51-questions-belong-here-as-opposed-to-area-51-discussion-zone) says either is fine, but I wanted to check about cross-posting in particular.

In this case, my query arises as a minority of questions on-topic in the proposed site might also be on-topic elsewhere. I’m seeking clarity on this.

---

For context, the question is [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32966/are-code-level-questions-on-topic-in-proposed-clinical-informatics-site) and the proposal is for [Clinical Informatics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127893/clinical-informatics).

Comment: "*seeking advice about the scope of a proposed site?*" I wonder if it might go well here. Disregarding PromptDesign.SE because it's more of an exception than a norm, there's a close reason "*Relates to only one specific network site*" on here. If you're looking for [tag:site-recommendation] based on a specific topic, then it should be on-topic, but I rarely see a discussion about *a specific site proposal* here nowadays.